# How do I connect this java function to a html form

Tags: javascript

I want to connect this Javascript function to a html form that has a text input and a button. When i enter a valid number, in console it would say "Valid" or "Invalid"

```
function validCNP( p_cnp ) {
var i=0 , year=0 , hashResult=0 , cnp=[] , hashTable=[2,7,9,1,4,6,3,5,8,2,7,9];
if( p_cnp.length !== 13 ) { return false; }
for( i=0 ; i<13 ; i++ ) {
    cnp[i] = parseInt( p_cnp.charAt(i) , 10 );
    if( isNaN( cnp[i] ) ) { return false; }
    if( i < 12 ) { hashResult = hashResult + ( cnp[i] * hashTable[i] ); }
}
hashResult = hashResult % 11;
if( hashResult === 10 ) { hashResult = 1; }
year = (cnp[1]*10)+cnp[2];
switch( cnp[0] ) {
    case 1  : case 2 : { year += 1900; } break;
    case 3  : case 4 : { year += 1800; } break;
    case 5  : case 6 : { year += 2000; } break;
    case 7  : case 8 : case 9 : { year += 2000; if( year > ( parseInt( new Date().getYear() , 10 ) - 14 ) ) { year -= 100; } } break;
    default : { return false; }
}
if( year < 1800 || year > 2099 ) { return false; }
return ( cnp[12] === hashResult );
```

}

Can someone help me with the html please?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and with [events](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/Events).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! Are you asking to run the function when your textbox gets changed?

If so, you can do it in pure JS like this:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change",function () {
  console.log("Input Changed");
  // You can put your validate code here
})
```

I'd suggest learning off of websites such as W3Schools or use YouTube to learn the basics of JavaScript.